# Multiple Lines in errorbar Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, data-science

The problem occurs when having a set of X values and Y values (41 to be exact) and I want an error bar, this works, but it creates a lot of lines instead only one.
Here is my code:

```
y_values = [
    np.mean(image_data['some_parameter'][x]) 
    for x in image_data['some_parameter']
]

yerr = [
    statistics.stdev(image_data['some_parameter'][x]) 
    for x in image_data['some_parameter']
]


x_values = list(image_data['some_parameter'].keys())

plt.errorbar(x_values, y_values, yerr=yerr, capsize=5, ecolor="red")
plt.show()
```

In the end, the result looks something like this:

[image: the plot that comes out]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to `x_values` being unsorted. You can fix it with something like

```
sorted_indices = np.argsort(x_values)
new_x_values = np.array(x_values)[sorted_indices]
new_y_values = np.array(y_values)[sorted_indices]
new_yerr = np.array(yerr)[sorted_indices]

plt.errorbar(new_x_values, new_y_values, yerr=new_yerr, capsize=5, ecolor="red",
             linestyle="-", marker="")
```

You can also disable the lines interconnecting the data points by setting `linestyle=""` and add markers by setting `marker="o"` for instance. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html) for info on markers and [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html) for the linestyle documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much, this never occured to me, have a wonderful day.